# Can't read request header `Content-Length` using `$http_content_length`

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I wan't to read client's header `Content-Length` and create new one with its value

```
proxy_set_header X-Content-Length-2   $http_content_length;
```

As a result `X-Content-Length-2` is missing on the server side but the original `Content-Length` is available

The same approach with `Content-Type` works

```
proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-2   $http_content_type;
```

Do I need to read `Content-Length` somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

It should be just `$content_length` instead of `$http_content_length` as per the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html).